# Rails 3- Devise - Authentication via web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I need to implement a login web service in RoR 3.
I applied Devise to a user model and it added some fields.

What I want to do is:
1- Client executes a REST service, sending user and password.
2- Server authenticates that (using encrypted_password field in User table) and returns an access token with an expiration time
3- Client sends that access token in all the services that he executes and if the token is not expired the server sends the response without error.

How can I implement this scheme using Devise. I have already applied Devise to user model.

Thanks!

Comment: Too late but here is a link where you can get some idea [http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise]

Comment: One more here http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/

Comment: @AbhayKumar, thanks but the first link is broken.

Comment: [here is the new one](http://zyphdesignco.com/blog/simple-auth-token-example-with-devise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Devise is not intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Devise doesn't do anything like that out of the box.

Devise could handle the initial authentication, for example there's a single line to uncomment to allow basic auth on email/password.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.http_authenticatable = true
```

Sending and storing the access token is something you'd have to home cook, to my knowledge Devise doesn't do anything like that. Perhaps a tokens model that belongs_to user?

You could create a custom Warden strategy to authenticate via your token, there is an example of how that might work at the bottom of devise.rb.

Talking about authentication tokens makes me think of Oauth, which is much more complicated than what you have in mind but has the advantage of being a standard of sorts. If you are curious about that route, I'd check out: https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2